# Print one number after the last word

Tags: arrays, c, text-files

```
while(!feof(fp)) {
  printf("\n %s %s %s", post.name, post.lastnamn, post.clubb);
  for(i = 1; i <= x; i++;)
  {
    printf(" %d", j.number[i]);
  }
  fread(&post, sizeof(postTyp), 1, fp);
}
```

I have created two *typedef struct* and I am referring to them with post and j.

I have created a program that asks for a users name, last-name and clubb and stores it in a text file. I have also created a program that creates `x` amount of numbers in the array `number[i]` and save it in a text file. `x` counts how many times you have run a program to create an name, last-name and clubb. So if you run the program 3 times 3 numbers will be created like example down below

So when i print it i get this

```
Hanna Svensson FCB 1 2 3
Fabian Svensson FCB 1 2 3
Patrik Svensson FCB 1 2 3
```

What i want is to print it like this

```
Hanna Svensson FCB 1
Fabian Svensson FCB 2 
Patrik Svensson FCB 3
```

Any tips for how I may accomplish this?

Comment: The first printf is inside a loop, right? Show that loop

Comment: Please do not describe code, instead provide a [mre]. Explaining shown code is of course appreciated but it should be available.

Comment: well it is in a while loop i posted i now "fp" is what my file name is

Comment: how is it possible you print the fields **before** to read them ? why your loop is not `while (fread(&post, sizeof(postTyp), 1, fp) == 1) { ...}` ? Note to call *feof* before any read return an unspecified result, and as you can see you do not need *feof* at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to only use the outer loop and not the inner one

```
i=1;
while(!feof(fp))
{
    printf("\n %s %s %s", post.name, post.lastnamn, post.clubb);
    printf(" %d", j.number[i]);
    i++;
    /* ...*/
}
```

Note aside: your while loop construct is very quetionable.

Comment: Please search for "Why is `while(!feof(fp))` always wrong?"

Comment: ah thanks did't think about that i could put it outside my while loop

Comment: You mean "inside" don't you?

Comment: well the while loop is program so it works for me, didn't want to include it because i thought it would confuse many people

Comment: had to include much other code in order for you to understand it, but yeah thanks for the heads up,  Yunnosch